# I'm having trouble formatting the print statement using a nested for loop

Tags: visual-c++

I am taking hard coded information of two arrays and creating the Union, Intersection and Difference of them.

My issue is that I can't get the Intersection or Difference to print with the right format.

I have tried a different variety of while loops with for and if statements, but can't quite get it. I know I'm close-ish. (Hopefully)

Main information:

```
int setA[] = {3,4,9,12,13,15};
int setB[] = {1,3,5,7,9};

int lenA = sizeof(setA) / sizeof(setA[0]); 
int lenB = sizeof(setB) / sizeof(setB[0]);

Difference(setA, setB, lenA, lenB);
Intersection(setA, setB, lenA, lenB);



void Intersection(int setA[], int setB[], int lenA, int lenB)
{
cout << "AnB = {";

for (int i = 0; i < lenA; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < lenB; j++)  
    {
        while(setA[i] == setB[j] && i < lenA - 1)
        {
            cout << setA[i++] << ", ";
        }

        if(i < lenA && setA[i] == setB[j])
        {
            cout << setA[i++];
        }
    }   
}

cout << "}";
cout << endl;

}

void Difference(int setA[], int setB[], int lenA, int lenB)
{

cout << "A - B = {";

for (int i = 0; i < lenA; i++)
{
    bool comp = false;              

    for (int j = 0; j < lenB; j++)

        if (setA[i] == setB[j])
        {
            comp = true;
            break;  
        }

    if(!comp)
    {
        cout << setA[i] << ",";
    }
}

cout << "}";
cout << endl;
}
```

I want the output to look like:

AnB = {3, 9} (Intersection)

A-B = {4, 12, 13, 15} (Difference)

What I am getting:

AnB = {3, 9, } (Intersection)

A-B = {4, 12, 13, 15, } (Difference)

I just need to get the commas at the end fixed, but don't know how.

Sorry if this question is way too long, I wasn't sure of how to get my issue out.

Comment: Everything would be simpler if you print the comma before the number, not after (except for the very first one, of course). It's easier to check for "is this the first number ever printed" than for "will there be another number after this?".

Comment: Thank you Igor, I was able to get some tutoring and we figured it out, but I agree with putting the comma before the number. It would have been much simpler. How could I have been able to tell that I was printing the very first number? What would that for loop look like? I'm still trying to get used to using them.

Comment: A rough sketch: `cout << "AnB = {"; bool first = true; for (...) { if (!first) {cout << ", "} first = false; cout << number }`